# Create a UNIQUE rule over custom field in WorkItem

Tags: tfs

I'm customizing the Work Item Definition Schema for the 'task' work item in TFS Server 2012. I've created a new field for hold a CustomerReference value. It works as I expected, but I would like add a UNIQUE restriction for security. I'd like add a rule than it makes imposible create two workItems with sme CustomerReference.

I think that none of the rules defined here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc339553(v=vs.90).aspx achieve my target.

Any idea? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort there is a way to write a custom plug-in that can enforce this server-side. See this link for more info on creating an ISubscriber plug-in: http://nakedalm.com/team-foundation-server-2010-event-handling-with-subscribers/

Unfortunately, the plug-in model doesn't allow you to prevent changes; but it could allow you to detect when somebody has violated the rule and react.  For example, it could send an email off to somebody, and possibly clear out the CustomerReference field from the duplicate.

Comment: This answer confirm my worst suspicions: it's no possible create a UNIQUE rule! Anyway it's an usefull trick, thanks.